# ThinkingSphinx with Passenger. Delta not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Localy it working fine. On remote server with Passenger, sphinx in this bin-directory:

```
which searchd
/usr/bin/searchd
```

Here is my config file:

```
production:
  quiet_deltas: true
  mem_limit: 128M
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 2
  morphology: stem_ru
  mysql41: 9406
  bin_path: '/usr/bin'
  searchd_binary_name: '/usr/bin/searchd'
  indexer_binary_name: '/usr/bin/indexer'
```

Delta not trigger in production...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the full path for the binary names (those settings are for some Linux distribution packages which rename searchd and indexer to be sphinxsearchd, etc).

So, remove your searchd_binary_name and indexer_binary_name settings and see if that helps.